# Force Bower to use latest version of a dependency

Tags: bower

I'm requiring `bootstrap` version `latest` in my `bower.json`. Today I've to add `bootstrap-vertical-tabs` to my dependencies, and I noticed that it depends on `bootstrap` version `~3.0.3`.

I thought when I run `bower update` my Bootstrap version wouldn't get changed, but I noticed that it got downgraded to 3.0.3. Is this a bug or is working as expected? Is there any way to force using `latest` version as I defined in my Bower manifest? Tried to use `bower update -F` but no luck.

I'm using Bower 1.3.1.

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found that using `latest` as a dependency version Bower doesn't resolve to latest version when  it tries to resolve conflicts, thus it ignores the `latest` version and won't ask for a suitable version for conflict resolution.

Had to tweak Bootstrap version to `3.1.*` in the manifest file to get the conflict resolution prompt when updating.

Comment: Great idea. I tried to manually tweak angular-animate in this same manner with no success.